# From a big PDF file how to convert only particular pages to HTML using Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

From a big PDF file how to convert only particular pages to HTML using Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of tools online that can do this. I suggest you one [here](http://www.pdfpdf.com/pdfconverter.html)

It works on Windows 7 and Vista.

> PDF Ripper is efficient software to extract image, text, chart, formula, vector drawings from Adobe PDF files. With this program, you can easily collect materials from existing PDF documents, and save them into HTML format, RTF format and plain text format.
>
> If you are looking for a converter program to **convert PDF to Word, PDF to RTF, PDF to HTML, PDF to Text** with a minimum loss of information while preserving the layout and graphics of the original PDF documents, you shouldn't miss PDF Ripper.